# Shiny- Multiplot function and coord_fixed

Tags: r, shiny

How can I modify the **multiplot function** to fit graphs that use `coord_fixed()` without white space between columns in Shiny plotOutput?

This is a small reproducible shiny app with the problem:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)
library(readr)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(grid)
library(ggforce) 
library(patchwork)
library(cowplot)

ui <- fluidPage(
   
   navbarPage("MotorBrain", 
              tabsetPanel(id = "inTabset",
                       tabPanel("Configurazione",
                       sidebarLayout(
                           sidebarPanel( 
                               sliderInput("input1", "N. utenti",
                                           min = 1, max = 133,
                                           value = 3),
                               sliderInput("nCol1", "Ncols",
                                           min = 1, max = 32,
                                           value = 1),
                               actionButton("goButton1", "Visualizza")),
                           fluidRow())),
   tabPanel("Visualizzazione", 
            fluidRow(
                uiOutput("outputTest1"))
            
   ))))




server <- function(input, output,session) {
   
   observeEvent(input$goButton1, {
       updateTabsetPanel(session, "inTabset", selected = "Visualizzazione")
   })
   
   input1<-eventReactive(input$goButton1,{
       input$input1
   })
   multiplot <- function(plots, plotlist=NULL, cols, layout=NULL,nUtenti) {
       require(grid)
       
      
       
       
       numPlots = nUtenti
       
       # If layout is NULL, then use 'cols' to determine layout
       if (is.null(layout)) {
           # Make the panel
           # ncol: Number of columns of plots
           # nrow: Number of rows needed, calculated from # of cols
           layout <- matrix(seq(1,cols * ceiling(numPlots/cols)),
                            ncol = cols, nrow = ceiling(numPlots/cols))
       }
       
       if (numPlots==1) {
           print(plots[[1]])
           
       } else {
           # Set up the page
           grid.newpage()
           pushViewport(viewport(layout = grid.layout(nrow(layout), ncol(layout))))
           
           # Make each plot, in the correct location
           for (i in 1:numPlots) {
               # Get the i,j matrix positions of the regions that contain this subplot
               matchidx <- as.data.frame(which(layout == i, arr.ind = TRUE))
               print(matchidx)
               print(plots[[i]], vp = viewport(layout.pos.row = matchidx$row,
                                               layout.pos.col = matchidx$col, width = unit(1, "npc")))
           }
       }
       
   }
   n=20
   output$outputTest1 <- renderUI({ 
       plots <- vector("list", length =  input1())
       for(t in 1: input1()) {
           df <- data.frame(
               x1 = runif(10,0, 1),
               y =runif(10,0, 1),
               x2 = sample(c(TRUE, FALSE), n, replace = T))
            
           p<-ggplot() +
               geom_point(aes(x=x1,y=y),data = df)+
               coord_fixed() +
               facet_grid(.~ x2)+
               xlim(0,100)+
               ylim(0,100)+
               theme_no_axes()+
               theme(legend.position = "none", strip.background = element_blank(),
                     strip.text.x = element_blank())+
               # the space is added to both sides, so we need to reduce by half
               theme(plot.margin = unit(c(0,0,0,0), "pt"))+
               theme(panel.spacing.x  = unit(0, "lines"))
           
           plots[[t]] <-p
           
       }
       
       output$plot_test1<- renderPlot({
         multiplot(plots,cols=input$nCol1, nUtenti=input1() )
           
       })
       
       plotOutput(outputId = "plot_test1")
       
   })                 
   
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I've a sequence of plots with `coord_fixed` and i need to put one beside other without white space, I need to use a layout with row and columns and the number of columns could vary.
If I arrange the graphs in two columns there is a white space in the middle, how can I remove it?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `coord_fixed` we are fixing the aspect ratio to 1 by default. To make the spacing between columns the dimensions of the plot need to change. I added two sliders to control the height and width. I don't know a formula to make this happen automatically without the user manual intervention though. For example, for two columns and 3 plots, making the width twice the hight works.

App:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)
library(readr)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(grid)
library(ggforce)
library(patchwork)
library(cowplot)

ui <- fluidPage(
  navbarPage(
    "MotorBrain",
    tabsetPanel(
      id = "inTabset",
      tabPanel(
        "Configurazione",
        sidebarLayout(
          sidebarPanel(
            sliderInput("input1", "N. utenti",
              min = 1, max = 133,
              value = 3
            ),
            sliderInput("nCol1", "Ncols",
              min = 1, max = 32,
              value = 2
            ),
            actionButton("goButton1", "Visualizza")
          ),
          fluidRow()
        )
      ),
      tabPanel(
        "Visualizzazione",
        #the two sliders
        sliderInput('height', 'height', min = 0, max = 5000, value =500),
        sliderInput('width', 'width', min = 0, max = 5000, value= 1000),
        br(),
        fluidRow(
          uiOutput("outputTest1")
        )
      )
    )
  )
)




server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$goButton1, {
    updateTabsetPanel(session, "inTabset", selected = "Visualizzazione")
  })

  input1 <- eventReactive(input$goButton1, {
    input$input1
  })
  multiplot <- function(plots, plotlist = NULL, cols, layout = NULL, nUtenti) {
    require(grid)




    numPlots <- nUtenti

    # If layout is NULL, then use 'cols' to determine layout
    if (is.null(layout)) {
      # Make the panel
      # ncol: Number of columns of plots
      # nrow: Number of rows needed, calculated from # of cols
      layout <- matrix(seq(1, cols * ceiling(numPlots / cols)),
        ncol = cols, nrow = ceiling(numPlots / cols)
      )
    }

    if (numPlots == 1) {
      print(plots[[1]])
    } else {
      # Set up the page
      grid.newpage()
      pushViewport(viewport(layout = grid.layout(nrow(layout), ncol(layout))))

      # Make each plot, in the correct location
      for (i in 1:numPlots) {
        # Get the i,j matrix positions of the regions that contain this subplot
        matchidx <- as.data.frame(which(layout == i, arr.ind = TRUE))
        print(matchidx)
        print(plots[[i]], vp = viewport(
          layout.pos.row = matchidx$row,
          layout.pos.col = matchidx$col, width = unit(1, "npc")
        ))
      }
    }
  }
  n <- 20
  output$outputTest1 <- renderUI({
    plots <- vector("list", length = input1())
    for (t in 1:input1()) {
      df <- data.frame(
        x1 = runif(10, 0, 1),
        y = runif(10, 0, 1),
        x2 = sample(c(TRUE, FALSE), n, replace = T)
      )

      p <- ggplot() +
        geom_point(aes(x = x1, y = y), data = df) +
        coord_fixed() +
        facet_grid(. ~ x2) +
        xlim(0, 100) +
        ylim(0, 100) +
        theme_no_axes() +
        theme(
          legend.position = "none", strip.background = element_blank(),
          strip.text.x = element_blank()
        ) +
        # the space is added to both sides, so we need to reduce by half
        theme(plot.margin = unit(c(0, 0, 0, 0), "pt")) +
        theme(panel.spacing.x = unit(0, "lines"))

      plots[[t]] <- p
    }

    output$plot_test1 <- renderPlot({
      multiplot(plots, cols = input$nCol1, nUtenti = input1())
    })

    # add hight and width arguments
    plotOutput(outputId = "plot_test1", height = paste0(input$height, "px"), width = paste0(input$width, "px"))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: It works! Thanks so much